# How to confirm that my compiled kernel is running on android after flashing it?

Tags: android, kernel, nexus-7

I compiled the kernel and flashed on nexus 7 with android-4.4.2.

Now I wanna check that my compiled kernel is running on the nexus device.

I checked with "uname -r" but it only gives the kernel name.

I checked on about phone on android device but I could not confirm still.

Is there any way I can put some information like tags somewhere which I can check after flashing that onto my device.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you all info:

```
uname -a
```

or

```
cat /proc/version
```